# PHP insert value into MySQL DB... but it's double

Tags: php, sql

here is the code...

```
function create_table($file){

    global $my_prepare_sql;

    $db = new PDO('myloginaccess', 'pasw');
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); //Error Handling

    $table_to_make = basename($file,'.TXT');

    // delete la table
    $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_to_make";
    $db->exec($sql);
    print("Table EXIST and DELETED.<br/>");

    $db->exec($my_prepare_sql[$table_to_make]['create']);
    print("Created table : $table_to_make<br/>");

    $stmt = $db->prepare($my_prepare_sql[$table_to_make]['insert']) or die ('prepare FAIL');

    //Lire le fichier
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) { print("<br/>File Open.<br/>"); }

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $nb_col =  '['.count($data).'] ';
        $stmt->execute($data);
    } 

    echo 'Nombre de collonnes : '.$nb_col .'<br/>';

    if (fclose($handle)) { print("File closed.<br/>");}

    return $db;
}
```

and this is the tables :

```
//--- BUREAUX --------------------------------------------------------
$my_prepare_sql['BUREAUX']['create'] = 
"CREATE TABLE BUREAUX ( 
CODE  nvarchar (24),
FIRME_CODE  nvarchar (24),
NOM_LEGAL  nvarchar (80),
NO_CIVIQUE  nvarchar (20),
NOM_RUE  nvarchar (120),
BUREAU  nvarchar (20),
MUNICIPALITE  nvarchar (100),
PROVINCE  nvarchar (20),
CODE_POSTAL  nvarchar (12),
TELEPHONE_1  nvarchar (40),
POSTE_1  int,
TELEPHONE_2  nvarchar (40),
POSTE_2  int,
TELEPHONE_FAX  nvarchar (40),
COURRIEL  nvarchar (300),
SITE_WEB  nvarchar (300),
DIRECTEUR_CODE  nvarchar (20) 
)";

$my_prepare_sql['BUREAUX']['insert'] =
"INSERT INTO BUREAUX (
CODE,
FIRME_CODE,
NOM_LEGAL,
NO_CIVIQUE,
NOM_RUE,
BUREAU,
MUNICIPALITE,
PROVINCE,
CODE_POSTAL,
TELEPHONE_1,
POSTE_1,
TELEPHONE_2,
POSTE_2,
TELEPHONE_FAX,
COURRIEL,
SITE_WEB,
DIRECTEUR_CODE) 
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

question, all the value in the table are DOUBLE
aa,aa,bb,bb,cc,cc insted of aa,bb,cc, why ?

Comment: This is a surprisingly badly written and presented questions from someone with decent reputation on SO.

Comment: Doesn't this call for basic debugging? Test outputs before insertion, see what `fgetcsv()` returns?

Comment: can you tell me what BAD ? @scrowler because i use PDO syntax

Comment: i find the PDO syntax ugly and unatural, but hey, it's the way to do it now...

Comment: i have found that the  $result = $query->fetchAll();
get the SAME value into [0] and [1] key of array... why ? i have no idea ... but its there

Answer (score 1):

Having the same data repeated twice does point to an error in the loop, or function called twice (etc).
As such it's a hard one for us to debug as we do not have access to all code involved to perform basic tests on the data flow from source to the point you get double data.

You can approach it easily yourself:

Mysql is the last line, where you say data is being doubled. So instead of inserting into the database, echo out the data and see if it produces the same issue (I presume it will).

If it does not echo the same double issue, then your issue is within the Mysql code somewhere or Mysql itself.
Echo out all the vars (etc) involved with Mysql, see where the issue starts.

If it does echoe out the same double issue, then you have eliminated Mysql.

You know it's nothing to do with mysql (which I'm going to presume it isn't) so then back track through your code.

Is it the loop? Does the data container (an array, variable, object whatever) have these values in it twice?
Echo out the container.

Does the source data have it twice?

Can only be a few things. Track back through your code echoing and checking each stage one by one you will eventually identify where the problem starts.

Comment: No the problem is in the fetchAll

Comment: Not sure why you said "no" I included that possibility in my flow of things to check. Glad you got it sorted however.

Comment: this help me found the BUG : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php the problem is ME not knowing PDO syntax enough !

Comment: You do now (well, some more anyway ;))

Answer (score 0):

this is my problem... it's not a bug it's a feature !

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [COLOUR] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [COLOUR] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

i change it to : fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and BINGO

my god, i hate PDO notation... so cryptic !